# Core blog module only shows two blog entries?

Tags: 7, nodes, upgrading

I've enabled the core blog module, but it only shows two entries on exampe.com/blog

If I "unpublish" one of them, it brings up the next published blog post, which shows me that it does recognize that there are additional blog posts.

There are about 137 in the database. How do I show them all with pagination? The core blog module doesn't seem to have any config settings.

EDIT: The site was recently migrated from D6 to D7, is there anything that may have caused this issue given this fact?

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce this behavior using your module set, but with fresh install and blog posts entered manually / generated with devel generate? If not, it's migration failure and your best bet is to export content from old site (you have backup, don't you) and import it to the new one, without Drupal's built in migration tool.

If this happen with fresh setup too, try changing theme to one of the supplied core themes. If it works, then, it means you have a bug in your templates. If it's not, I need to get more info to further expand my answer.